# Render [object HTMLElement] on webpage as an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This may be a simple answer but for some reason when I do the following code

```
$(value).closest('a').find('i.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star');

console.log(navigationButtonIcon);

// Append favourite item to favourites list
$("#favouritesList").append("<li><a id=" + favouriteLinkID + ">"+ navigationButtonIcon + favouriteValue + "</span><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right removeFavourite'></i></a></li>");
```

**It shows this in console log:**

```
<i class=​"fa fa-dashboard fa-fw selectNavigationBTNIcon">​::before​</i>​
```

**and shows this when I try and display it as an element on the page:**

```
[object HTMLElement]
```

What am I doing wrong that it's not showing the `[object HTMLElement]` as the actual line of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding the element object as a string, which automatically casts it to `[object HTMLElement]`. You need to either add it *as an element* or *as an HTML string*.

As an HTML string (gotten using DOM `.outerHTML`):

```
$("#favouritesList").append("<li><a id=" + favouriteLinkID + ">"+ navigationButtonIcon.outerHTML + favouriteValue + "</span><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right removeFavourite'></i></a></li>");
```

As an element (using jQuery `.prepend()`):

```
$("#favouritesList").append("<li><a id=" + favouriteLinkID + ">"+ favouriteValue + "</span><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right removeFavourite'></i></a></li>").find('#'+favouriteLinkID).prepend(navigationButtonIcon);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! First answer and it was the correct answer :D